# Breeze Local Query for EnumType

Tags: enums, breeze

I setup WebApi method for Lookups which return

```
 public Object Lookups()
 {
    var durations = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Duration));
    var status = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Status));
    return new { durations, status };
 }
```

Then I make a query to the server with breeze

```
 return entityQuery.from('Lookups')
         .using(manager).execute()
         .then(querySucceeded, _queryFailed);

    function querySucceeded(data) {

        console.log("Retrieving [Lookups] " + data);
        return true;
   }
```

Now later on I want to get those lookups from cache, please note that in metadata my Enums reside under "EnumType", It looks like breeze not provide support yet to retrieve enums from server side so I returning them as a Lookups. Now, I am wondering how can I get them locally to reduce extra round trip?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "get them locally"? Do you mean query them from cache or do you mean define them in cache w/o first having to retrieve from the server via your `Lookups` query?

Comment: Yes, I want to get them from cache after getting it first from the server on the application startup. They are not entities so I can't get them through entityQuery.from('Duration').. because there are no resource name exist. So how would I get them from cache?

Comment: Also, Is there any plan that breeze will provide support to get Enums on client side in order to fill dropdown or some other cool stuffs instead of returning them as Lookups? Although they are present in metadata but there are no method exposed to get them something like entityQuery.getEnumType('Duration')..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET Enums are supported with the regular Web API. Their type names appear in metadata and are recognized by Breeze.

I don't think the enum values are propagated to the client automatically (that would be nice) but you can send them to the client by other means such as you are doing with a lookups endpoint.

> The Web API **OData** does not support enums yet either. In fact, it dies if a property returns an enum whereas WCF Data Services is content to deal with their string names. Nothing we can do about this defect of Web API OData at the moment.

Enums are not entities and I don't think you want to fake them as entities on the client. You could but **I** wouldn't.

Because they are not entities, Breeze won't store them in cache. Your query returns JavaScript simple objects, not entities, and there is no cache query that could find them.

I think what I would do in your situation is capture these enum values as array properties of a `datacontext` service ... the same service that your are using (I hope) to encapsulate your Breeze-based data access activities so that ViewModels interact with the `datacontext` rather than directly with Breeze components.

Accordingly, your lookups query success callback might look like this:

```
// Inside the datacontext service
var isReady = null;
var dc = {
     ready: ready,
     Duration: [],
     Status: [],
     ...
}

return dc;
///////////////
function ready() {
   return isReady || (isReady = getReady())); // returns the ready promise
}

function getReady() {
   // stuff you do to prime the pump
   // returns a promise that is "true" when you've completed your
   // preparatory async tasks such as fetching lookups
   ...
}
...
function lookupsQuerySucceeded(data) {
    console.log("Retrieved [Lookups] " + data);
    dc.Duration = data.results.Duration;
    dc.Status = data.results.Status;
    return true;
}
```

I'm leaving out details but I hope you get the idea.

There is only one trip to the server with this technique, a single visit to get the initial stuff and populate the cache and/or (in this case) properties of the `datacontext` itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for great explanation and suggestion. So what is your opinion Sir, Am I choosing a right path to get enums from the server as lookups? As you can see, I am only returning back Enum Names, will breeze automatically populate their related value back on the server when I call save changes to an Entity? Also, don't you think it would be great if there is a method on EntityQuery to populate Enums on the client when we have it in metadata, that will no longer required to make call to the server? May be I am wrong but that's what I think, please put your suggestion on it. Thanks

Comment: **Yes Breeze handles enum names properly as values** if the server is the Web API (not Web API OData). Breeze sends the string name back and the Web API's model binding turns that into the enum value. **Yes the enum values are available** in the metadata generated by EF and **sent to a Breeze client**. I agree Breeze should pick them up automatically and put them somewhere so you don't have to make a separate request for them **or extract them from the raw metadata passed to the `MetadataStore.fetchMetadata` success callback**. It's on our backlog. Meanwhile, you'll have to get them by hand.

Comment: If your curious about how to get the enum values from the rawMetadata returned by `MetadataStore.fetchMetadata`, see [DocCode *metadataTests.js*](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/net/DocCode/DocCode/tests/metadataTests.js)

Comment: Sir, I need your quick help related to similar one. Now I have duration array like you suggested, basically a javascript array object which contain "enumName" and "enumDisplayName" property for better user experience. The problem is how can I create a nullo object in this case. If this were an entity I can easily create using Breeze create Entity initial values parameter. But how would I create in this case. can you please suggest? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your meta data (I have loaded into a variable window.app.metadata) contains enum values, then you can

**1. Write js code to extract those enum in js dictionary**

```
   JSON.parse(window.app.metadata).schema.enumType.forEach(function (enumType) {
        var newEnumValues = [];

        enumType.member.forEach(function (enumValue) {
            var newEnumValue = { id: enumValue.value, name: enumValue.name };
            newEnumValues.push(newEnumValue);
        });

        enumDictionary[enumType.name] = newEnumValues;
    });
```

**2. Write a method to get enum value based upon enum name and id.**

```
    function GetEnumDictionaryValue(enumName, enumValueId) {
        var result = null;
        enumDictionary[enumName].some(function (enumValue) {
            if (enumValue.id == enumValueId) {
                result = enumValue.name;
                return;
            }
        });

        return result;
    }
```